# create a .txt file that lists all files in directory, using Matlab on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, matlab, list, text

I wrote this on my Matlab code for my MacOs:

```
folder_list = 'folder_list.txt';
cd(folder_paraboles)
if exist(folder_list) == 0
    commande = ['ls >',folder_list];
    unix(commande)
end
```

Does anyone can give me the corresponding line code on Matlab Windows? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `unix` to get the directory listing, you should just use the built-in `dir` or `ls` to get a list of files and then write them out to a file using MATLAB's built-in ability to write to files.

```
files = dir(pwd);

fid = fopen('output.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid ,'%s\n', files.name);
fclose(fid);
```